# Outlook Switches, Emails being sent to Outbox

Tags: outlook, office365

Im trying to create a desktop shortcut of Outlook that auto-generates an email to a specific department. At the moment, the switches being used are /c ipm.note /m "department email". Once the email is sent, it is being sent to an Outbox. Is there a way to send the email without it timing out and being sent to the Outbox where it waits until Outlook is open to send the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to send the email without it timing out and being sent to the Outbox where it waits until Outlook is open to send the email?

Nope. You can automate Outlook from any external application (using COM Automation) where you may call the sync objects to synchronize the Outbox folder with the server to deliver the item to recipients. The [SyncObject.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start) method begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified `Send\Receive` group. For example:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
 "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
 syc.Start 
End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```